# MeteorJS: Collection always returns count of 0

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

I have an app that has a collection called `Cities`.

Right now, all I am trying to do is to get the `console`to print the count of documents in the collection, but it only returns 0

Client.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('cities');
Meteor.autorun(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('jobs', Session.get('currentIndustryOnet'));
});

Meteor.startup(function(){
  if(!Session.get('jobsLoaded'))
    Session.set('jobsLoaded', true);

  if(! Session.get('map')) {
    gmaps.initialize();
  }

  Deps.autorun(function(){
    console.log(Cities.find().count())
  });
});
```

If I log into the mongo shell and run:
`db.cities.find().count()`

The count returned is `29467`, so I know there are records that exist. Not sure what I am doing wrong here

Code Structure:

`project_dir/client/client.js`

```
Meteor.subscribe('cities');

Meteor.autorun(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('jobs', Session.get('currentIndustryOnet'), function(){
    console.log(Cities.find({}).count());
  });
});
```

`project_dir/server/server.js`

```
Meteor.publish('jobs', function(onet_code){
  var cursor, options = {sort: {"dateacquired": -1}};
   if(onet_code && onet_code != 'all'){
    cursor = Jobs.find({onet: onet_code}, options);
   } else {
    cursor = Jobs.find({}, options);
   }

   return cursor;
 });

Meteor.publish('cities');
```

`project_dir/model.js`:

```
Cities = new Meteor.Collection("cities");
Jobs = new Meteor.Collection("jobs");

Jobs.allow({
  insert: function(id) {
    return false;
  },
  update: function(id, options) {
    return true;
  }
});

createJob = function(options) {
  var id = Random.id();
  var onet = Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')
  Meteor.call('createJob', _.extend({_id: id}, options));
  return id;
}

Meteor.methods({
  createJob: function(options) {
    var id = options._id || Random.id();
    Jobs.insert({
      _id: id,
      lat: options.lat || '',
      lng: options.lng || '',
      title: options.title,
      url: options.url,
      company: options.company,
      address: options.address,
      dateacquired: options.dateacquired,
      onet: options.onet,
      jvid: options.jvid
    });

    return id;
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you `publishing` these documents? Or are you using the `autopublish` package?

Comment: I updated my question with better project structure

Comment: What is `Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')` while making the `subscribe` call?

Comment: That is set from a click event from a drop down list

Comment: Add `autopublish` package to your project.

Comment: As per their documentation, you should remove the `autopublish` package when going to a "production" environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish your cities collection:

Instead of :

```
Meteor.publish("cities")
```

You should have :

```
Meteor.publish("cities", function() {
    return Cities.find()
});
```